# .htaccess GET parameter value to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, http, get

I will like to do this request in the browser:

```
https://file.domain.com/iums50.js
```

But Im really doing a request for the page:

```
https://file.domain.com/get.php?f=iums50.js
```

I don't want to redirect the user, I will like to put the content of get.php?f=iums50.js in https://file.domain.com/iums50.js, using .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /get.php?f=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect the request from :

```
/foo.bar
```

to

```
/get.php?f=foo.bar
```

`-d` means this is a directory and `-f` means this is a file. `RewriteCond` ition checks to see that the request is not `!` for an existent directory or file before rewriting the request to `/get.php` .